# ubuntu_22 : ROS2_humble :/usr/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:fatal error: pcl/conversions.h: No such file or directory

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-dock

Recently I started working in ROS2, while using some of pcl function I face below error.

For #include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
I am getting the fatal error

```
/usr/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:44:10: fatal error: pcl/conversions.h: No such file or directory
   44 | #include <pcl/conversions.h>
```

Platform : Ubuntu 22

ros-humble-pcl-conversions        2.4.0-4jammy.20221207.034537 amd64        Provides conversions from PCL data types and ROS message types

libpcl-dev                        1.12.1+dfsg-3build1          amd64        Point Cloud Library - development files

Comment: So is the file actually missing, or is the issue that your build process is not adding `/usr/include/pcl-1.12/` to the include path?

Comment: Yeah, It was one of the missing part from my try, but I added that also in CMakeList 
`find_package(PCL COMPONENT REQUIRED)`, AND missed this part : 

`include_directories(
  include
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)`
and before `ament_package()` add this - `ament_export_include_directories(include)`


Now it is working.

Thank you for responding